# Different ways of organizing message database at client in Java

Tags: java, database, message, client-side

Can you please point me to the right direction on the following issue:
We have:

 - Signed java applet / JWS

 - Messages going back and forth between different users

 - Messages must be kept on a local pc

Which options do you see for keeping messages on a local pc?

 - Local database?

 - Text files in some self-developed format?

Have anybody tried doing anything like this? With database I am a bit worried about compatibility at different platforms. With text file - obviously about performance, when the number of messages saved goes up.

Thanks for response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it depends on what you want to do with those messages later, I'd probably go for a database, preferably an embedded one, like for example Berkeley DB, Apache Derby or H2. (Again, the exact choice depends on how much data you need to handle and what operations you'll need to perform on the data.)

Comment: By "embedded" do you mean that it is part of standard Java installation?

Comment: No, just that it runs in the same Java VM as your applet, no separate installation needed.